# Why does react router work on localhost but will not work after Heroku deployment?

Tags: react-native, heroku, react-router-dom

there are a few posts like this and I have tried other solutions such as adding a .htaccess file, and adding 'process.env.PUBLIC_URL' ahead of each route to get the relative route location, but nothing seems to be working with the new react-router-dom package which has been released...

The application will load the '/' login page no problem on startup in heroku, and in there a direct  will move to another page, however after successful login I use 'window.location.assign("/Home")' to try to auto navigate back to the home page. This gets a 404 error.
Similarly, manually adding locations into the top bar also give 404 errors..

I have tried the fixes provided in other posts, but they are all for the old react-router-dom package (before they moved away from switch and started using BrowserRouter).

Can anyone help figure out why my router won't identify addresses added to the window location??

The application is currently deployed at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/octowatch-scratch

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AboutKPI from './pages/AboutKPI';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import BreachComposition from './pages/BreachComposition';
import BreachesPerWard from './pages/BreachesPerWard';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import AddAccount from './pages/AddAccount';
import ManageAccounts from './pages/ManageAccounts';
import OverallBreaches from './pages/OverallBreaches';
import AddData from './pages/AddData';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import { lightGreen, brown } from '@mui/material/colors';
import './App.css';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {main: lightGreen[900]},
    secondary: {main: brown[500]},
  },
});

function App() {

  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element = {<Login/>} />
              <Route exact path="/AboutKPI" element = {<AboutKPI/>} />
              <Route exact path="/BreachComposition" element = {<BreachComposition/>} />
              <Route exact path="/BreachesPerWard" element = {<BreachesPerWard/>} />
              <Route exact path="/Login" element = {<Login/>} />
              <Route exact path="/Home" element = {<Home/>} />
              <Route exact path="/Dashboard" element = {<Dashboard/>} />
              <Route exact path="/AddAccount" element = {<AddAccount/>} />
              <Route exact path="/ManageAccounts" element = {<ManageAccounts/>} />
              <Route exact path="/OverallBreaches" element = {<OverallBreaches/>} />
              <Route exact path="/AddData" element = {<AddData/>} />
          </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**Login Page ()**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid,Paper, Avatar, TextField, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Api from "../api.js"
import LockIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Lock';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Login(breachesCallback) {
    const paperStyle={padding :20,height:'70vh',width:280, margin:"20px auto"}
    const avatarStyle={backgroundColor:'#1bbd7e'}
    const btnstyle={margin:'8px 0'}
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    var now = new Date();
    function validateForm() {
        return email.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
    }

    function goHome () {
        window.location.assign("/Home");
    }

    function goReset () {
        window.location.assign("/UpdatePassword");
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        Api.noToken().post('/users/login', {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            resetDate: Math.floor(((now / 8.64e7) - 150.604166666))
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if(response.status === 204){//this means a password reset still needs to occur here
            Api.withToken().get('/breaches/')
            .then(res => {
                breachesCallback(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
            }).then(goReset());
            }
            else if(response.status === 200){
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            Api.withToken().get('/breaches/')
            .then(res => {
                breachesCallback(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
            }).then(goHome());
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert("Invalid username or password")
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Grid>
                    <Paper elevation={10} style={paperStyle}>
                        <Grid align='center'>
                            <Avatar style={avatarStyle}><LockIcon/></Avatar>
                            <h2>Sign In</h2>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextField label='Username' placeholder='Enter username' fullWidth required onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                        <TextField label='Password' placeholder='Enter password' type='password' fullWidth required onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                            <Checkbox
                                name="checkedB"
                                color="primary"
                            />
                            }
                            label="Remember me"
                        />
                        <Button type='submit' disabled={!validateForm()} color='primary' variant="contained" style={btnstyle} fullWidth>Sign in</Button>
                        <Typography >
                            <Link to="#" >
                                Forgot password ?
                            </Link>
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography > Do you have an account ?
                            <Link to="/AddAccount" >
                                Sign Up 
                            </Link>
                        </Typography>
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </form>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of looking I've finally found the most up to date tool you are meant to use for react router in the latest update (currently 6.1.1)

This is about 3 posts down in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) (the other answers are all for older versions of react router and will not work)

The answer is simple:
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

then in your function add a simpler variable for useNavigate:
let navigate = useNavigate();

and replace your window.location.assign("/Home") with navigate("/Home", { replace: true });

(obviously could also just say useNavigate("/Home", {replace:true})

Comment: I found another issue as well. If you don't have a leading '/' before the address to your build's index.html file then it will fail to load the index file on page refresh:    app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/./client/build/index.html'));
});